# Program for Employee management

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i need the code of a program in python. for employee management using the import csv module.also there should be a unique id generated for each employee in sequence.
i have done till here..please help..

```
import csv
import random
employee=[]
EmpID=random.randint(0,100)
EmpID=str(EmpID)
print("The Employee ID is:",EmpID)

EmpName=input("Please enter emp name:")
Designation=input("Please enter emp designation:")
DOB=input("Please enter emp DOB:")
Gender=input("Please enter emp gender:")
C_Number=input("Please enter emp Contact Number:")
E_mail=input("Please enter emp email:")
Address=input("Please enter emp address:")
Salary=input("Please enter emp salary:")
DOJ=input("Please enter emp date of joining:")

employee.append(EmpID)
employee.append(EmpName)
employee.append(Designation)
employee.append(DOB)
employee.append(Gender)
employee.append(C_Number)
employee.append(E_mail)
employee.append(Address)
employee.append(Salary)
employee.append(DOJ)
with open('D:\\employeemgmnt.csv','wb',) as employee1:
     writer=csv.writer(employee1)
     #employee1Writer.writerow(['EmpID','EmpName','Designation','DOB','Gender','C.Number','E-mail','Address','Salary','DOJ'])
     writer.writerow(employee)
     #employee.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [uuid — UUID objects according to RFC 4122](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html)

```
import uuid

EmpID = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

Example EmpID:
    `838b0e1c-1443-40cd-92bd-d63cd7f0c67c`